# Can a Lipshitz Continuous function on an interval with a Uniformly continuous derivative have a nonexistant second derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

if $f:\left[a,b\right]\mapsto\mathbb R$ Is Lipschitz Continuous

And

$f':\left[a,b\right]\mapsto\mathbb R$ exists for all $x \in [a,b]$ and is  is Uniformly Continuous

then
Does $f'':\left[a,b\right]\mapsto\mathbb R$ exist on all $x  \in \mathbb [a,b]$

**Edit** This is part of a much larger question that is also on this site. Also I have completely reworded the question.

Comment: There is a very familiar example of a function which is Lipschitz continuous and is not differentiable at a point. I recommend finding it and thinking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = |x|.$$

Lipschitz Continuous on $[-1,1]$, does not even have a derivative in $0$, therefore $f'$ is not uniformly continuous on $[-1,1]$.

As the answer to your edit: You cannot prove the converse. $f'$ being uniformly continuous imples that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, but the converse is not true.

Edit: You completely reworded your question, so here is the answer to your current question:

Take $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2&\text{ if } x\geq0\\ -x^2&\text{ if } x\leq 0\end{cases}$$
defined on $[-1,1]$.

$f'(x) = |x|$ is then uniformly continuous and $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. $f''$ does not exist for $x=0$

Comment: Oh oops I knew that. I have to reword my question. Thanks very much for the timely answer though

Comment: I edited my answer. Still, the answer is no.